# Rails Order records by most conditions meet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

Order elements that exist in association, where the first element will be the element that exist in the most selected associations.
In other words order elements by most assosietions exist from given list.
It sounds complicated, so here the working example, but super slow one.

We want to sort the cars, by the most drivers can drive them

```
# we have some ids of driver seleted by user
dynamic_drivers_ids = [1,2,3,100,5]

@cars = Car.all.includes(:driving_levels)
@cars.sort_by {|e| (e.driving_level.map(&:driver_id) & dynamic_drivers_ids ).size * -1 }
```

It takes about 1 a second to load, with only 20 cars.
But now we have situation with 100 cars, and it takes decades to calculate it.

How can we write sql request to order like that?
its not working, but show the some logic:

```
Car.includes(:driving_levels).order("driving_level.id IN = ? AND driving_level.size", dynamic_drivers_ids)
```

The Db tables look like:

```
class Car
  has_many :driving_levels
  has_many :drivers, through: driving_levels


class DrivingLevel
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :driver

class Driver
  has_many :driving_levels
  has_many :cars, through: driving_levels
```

Comment: What is your db?

Comment: It seems `cars belongs_to driving_level`. So it is strange to see `driving_level.map(&:driver_id)`. Please, provide models code.

Comment: I have updated the question with tables

Comment: I think this belongs in codereview, as it's code optimalisation https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

What about left join `driving_levels` but only those which have `driver_id` in `dynamic_drivers_ids` (hope `dynamic_drivers_ids` doesn't come from a user, otherwise it's sql-injection-prone)? Then you can group and order by the count of the driving levels?

It's going to look like this:

```
 Car
   .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN driving_levels ON
           driving_levels.id = cars.driving_level_id AND 
           driving_level.driver_id IN (#{dynamic_drivers_ids})")
   .group(:id).order("COUNT(driving_levels.id)")
```

Comment: Not sure if you can insert array into sql string :(

Comment: Yea, my mistake, you need the brackets there. Edited

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `where` and `references` here:

```
dynamic_drivers_ids = [1,2,3,100,5]

@cars = Car.includes(:driving_level).
            references(:driving_level).
            where(driving_level: {id: dynamic_drivers_ids})
```

What happens here is it will join tables `cars` and `driving_level`, and pull ONLY `driving_level` records, which have these ids (you wont have to do: `e.driving_level.map(&:driver_id) & dynamic_drivers_ids`). You wont pull all `driving_level` records anymore. 
This should speed up drastically.

Secondary: order by association. The easiest way is to use column, which counts our associations, and then order over it:

```
@cars = Car.select('COUNT(driving_levels.id) as driving_levels_size').
            includes(:driving_level).
            references(:driving_level).
            where(driving_level: {id: dynamic_drivers_ids}).
            group('cars.id, driving_levels.id').
            order('driving_levels_size')
```

This should return you correct order and correct records of assocations.

Comment: There is an error PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "driving_levels_size" does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Try this if `driving_levels` includes records with `driver_id` 1,2,3,100,5.

```
select_clause = <<~SQL
  cars.*,
  ( SELECT count(DISTINCT driver_id) FROM driving_levels
    WHERE driver_id IN (1,2,3,100,5)
       OR car_id=cars.id ) as driver_cnt
SQL

Car
  .select(select_clause)
  .order('driver_cnt DESC')
  .to_a
```